# Are event_base_loop and event_base_dispatch thread safe?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, libevent

Are the `event_base_loop()`(publisher thread) and `event_base_dispatch()`(subscriber thread) functions thread safe? Recently I checked my application for any synchronization errors using `valgrind's` `helgrind` tool. In the report it's mentioned that there exists a race condition between `event_base_loop()` and `event_base_dispatch()` even though both these functions are called with different `struct event_base` variables (`struct event_base base_pub`(publisher thread) and `struct event_base base_sub` (subscriber thread)). Below is the sample code

Publisher Thread

```
struct event_base base_pub = event_base_new();
while (true) {
    ... // publish data
    event_base_loop(base_pub, EVLOOP_NONBLOCK);
    sleep(1);
    ...
}
```

Subscriber Thread

```
struct event_base base_sub = event_base_new();
while (true) {
    ... // register subscriber callback function
    event_base_dispatch(base_sub);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

They are thread-safe, if you enable locking/condition variables through:

`evthread_use_pthreads();`

You also need to link with `libevent_pthreads`. [Note](http://www.wangafu.net/%7Enickm/libevent-2.1/doxygen/html/) that:

> Before you call any other Libevent functions, you need to set up the
> library. If you're going to use Libevent from multiple threads in a
> multithreaded application, you need to initialize thread support –
> typically by using evthread_use_pthreads() or
> evthread_use_windows_threads().

> Currently, only one thread can be dispatching a given event_base at a
> time. If you want to run events in multiple threads at once, you can
> either have a single event_base whose events add work to a work queue,
> or you can create multiple event_base objects.